# url_rewrite duplicates during migration. How it solve?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I started to do migration from magento 1. And i faced with some very weird issue. Namely during  `Url Rewrite Step`. This error looks:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'footwear/sneakers/slip-on.html-2' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'

For several few days i liking for solution, i found [issue on github](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/81). There i found recommendation

> With auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates=1 migration completed without
>   errors

I added this to my configuration file of migration. This looks like:

```
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">    
    <options>    
 <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>1</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    </options>
</config>
```

But this error it stays.

**What is my mistake?  How i can solve this ?**

- *Migration tool version - 2.3.1*
- *Magento destination version - 2.3.1*
- *Magento source version - 1.14.0.1.*